# Reformulation of matrix trace maximization to an SDP

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, positive-semidefinite, linear-matrix-inequality

Consider the following optimization problem:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\max_{X,Y} \;& \mathrm{Tr}[A Y] + \mathrm{Tr}[(B X B^\top)^{1/2}]\\
\mbox{s.t.} \; & Y = C - F^\top B^\top (X + D)^{-1} B F\\
& X \succeq 0, Y\succeq 0,
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
where $A, B, C, D$ and $F$ are known matrices of appropriate dimension. Moreover, $A, B$, and $D$ are positive semidefinite.

This problem is intractable due to the inverse in the first constraint and the square root in the second trace in the objective. My question is, is it possible to reformulate this problem into an SDP?

Here are the reformulations I tried:

1. I replaced the first equality with an inequality:
   \begin{equation*}
   Y \preceq C - F^\top B^\top (X + D)^{-1}  B F.
   \end{equation*}

(Not sure if this is allowed)
Then, I used the Schur complement lemma to write the inequality constraint as the following LMI constraint:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
C - Y & F^\top B^\top \\ B F & X + D
\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0,
\end{equation*}
with
\begin{equation*}
X + D\succeq 0.
\end{equation*}

2. For the objective function, I've introduced a new variable $U \succeq 0$ and a new constraint
   \begin{equation*}
   (BXB^\top)^{1/2} \succeq U,
   \end{equation*}
   which again can be written as the following LMI constraint:
   \begin{equation*}
   \begin{bmatrix}
   B X B^\top & U \\ U & I
   \end{bmatrix}\succeq 0.
   \end{equation*}

As a result, the final form of the problem I obtained is as follows:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\max_{X,Y, U} \;& \mathrm{Tr}[A Y] + \mathrm{Tr}[U]\\
\mbox{s.t.} \; & \begin{bmatrix}
Y - C & FB \\ B^\top F^\top & X + D
\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0\\
& \begin{bmatrix}
B X B^\top & U \\ U & I
\end{bmatrix}\succeq 0.
\\
&X + D\succeq 0\\
& X \succeq 0, Y\succeq 0, U\succeq 0.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

I would like to know whether my reformulations presented above are valid.

Comment: Is $A$ postive semidefinite? If so your first rewriting would make the problem unbounded. Could you edit the question with any properties of the other matrices $A,B,C,D,F$?

Comment: Thank you for the point! I've edited the question. $A$ is positive definite.

Comment: Great thanks, the first point looks good to me now but looking at the second point I'm unsure. Your block PSD constraint implies that $BXB^T \geq U^2$ and by monotonicity of square root we have $BXB^T \geq U^2 \implies \sqrt{BXB^T} \geq U$. However, note this is not an iff because $X \mapsto X^2$ is not operator monotone. This means there could be feasible points of the problem with the constraint $ \sqrt{BXB^T} \geq U$ that are not feasible points of the problem with the constraint $BXB^T \geq U^2$. In general this leads to an inner approximation to the original problem.